# How to get the bluetooth profiles status in iOS application

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth

I want to get the bluetooth profiles i.e. ACL, Headset etc status in my application as iOS device gets connected with remote bluetooth device. I am not able to find anything related to it.

Can anyone please help me achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching is  MPVolumeView. Check it-
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview

**Updated**- you can observe audio route change AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioRouteChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Also you can get the Audio routs from -

```
for( AVAudioSessionPortDescription *portDescription in route.outputs )
{
    headphonesLocated |= ( [portDescription.portType 
  isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones] );
}
```

Comment: I don't think it provides the profiles based on my requirements. MPVolumeView only provides the current audio output routes.

Comment: Are you looking for AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification ?? i've updated the answer. plz have a look

Comment: I have already tried AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification but it also gives only current route as in the routes that are being used but not the profiles that are devices connected with. Also it doesn't provides all the profiles, it only gives HFP and A2DP for remote devices. Not a solution for me but  thanks for response though